# DLL Missing on Staged Deployment to Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

Im using Windows Azure to host some production websites.  Today I tried out the "staged publishing" (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) feature, but Im having some issues...

I log onto my build machine, download my appropriate version of code, build and deploy to my TEST website on Azure.  I login to TEST, click around, and all is fine.

I then update my publish settings to point to my Azure staged deployment website.  When I deploy, I yellow screen getting a "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

So Im deploying from one machine, and one deployment is fine, the other is not.  The only other thing I change is the "Solution Configuration" on publish.  When I publish to test, I use one configuration, when I publish to my "staged" environment, it's another.

*EDIT*: I deployed to my test env when he staged solution configuration, and things deployed fine.. so I think I removed the possibility that the solution configuration is part of the problem..

Has anyone else ran into this?  Not sure if it's a staged deployment issue.. or something with Visual Studio.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the `Copy Local` property of that assembly reference in Visual Studio to `true`?  Maybe it's in the GAC on your test box and not on your staging box?

Comment: Thanks @TroyCarlson, all local DLL's are set to Copy Local.  When I got my build machine running, this DLL was a thorn in my side, and the machine wouldn't run the site until I installed Microsoft Ent Library on the PC as well.  I thought this issue was behind me since I had successfully deployed since then...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's been so sporadic, but in the end, it did have to do with the DLL's I was referencing\including in my project.  I published to a local directory, took a look at the bin directory, and found that the DLL's referenced on the yellow screen were not there.  In the end, I found appropriate copies, added them to a local "lib" directory within my website project, then added a direct reference to them, so they would be available on subsequent publishes.

Comment: Your exact issue has been driving me nuts for the last couple of weeks. Even more so in that it's been sporadic. I can't nail down a cause. Publish to a deployment slot, and it's squeaky bum time waiting to see if I'll get yellow screen of death as one (and always the same one) DLL is 'missing.' It MIGHT have something to do with the 'precompile before publishing' settings, but I still can't say for sure.

Comment: Anyway, as the DLL in question is one of my project DLLs, adding a special lib directory isn't an option. The damn thing is explicitly referenced from another DLL (that *does* get published), so I'm reduced to just asking why, why, o Azure Gods, why. (CopyLocal is true, etc etc.)